# Analog CMOS layout finger size

Tags: integrated-circuit, cmos

Analog CMOS layout finger size

I am doing analog CMOS layout in under 65nm processes.

What is the "rule" on the finger size I use for layout? Is there a rule of thumb for this?

For example, say I have a simple 2 stage opamp with an NMOS differential pair with PMOS active load and a second stage which is a common source stage. So I have three stacks to layout - a PMOS stack, and two NMOS stacks if you include the biasing for the NMOS differential pair.

You have a total width of a transistor but you can have transistor fingers each with their own width and then the amount of fingers*finger width = total width.  So how to pick the finger width is the question.

Comment: That’s an excellent question that results in better or worse mismatch of  RdsOn between P channel and N channel

Comment: Wouldn't the total transistor width be the more important variable? Or is the question asking about changing finger width while maintaining a constant overall transistor width?

Comment: How to to pick the actual finger width from the total transistor width.

Answer (score 1):

Go  for convenient sizes, that you can interdigitate to get thermal matching and implant matching.

Also keep the surrounding structures (wells, active, metal) identical for FETs you need to match.

===============================================

How to pick the actual finger width (say W/L = 100/0.5)?

Determine how you want/need to pack the circuit into available space.

If no space constraint, you should still use multiple stripes because sharing drains will reduce the parasitic capacitance, and give you a free Bandwidth boost.

Comment: Thank you for your message, I understand this, but how to to pick the actual finger width from the total transistor width.